# Testcontainers Ryuk fails when running with Tilt

Tags: docker, minikube, testcontainers

I have a Spring Boot application. My integration tests are working fine when I run them with Maven. However, when I use [Tilt](https://tilt.dev) to run them to build my image to deploy on Minikube, I get a Testcontainers error :

```
2024-01-22T20:26:34.149+01:00  INFO 11724 --- [my-service] [           main] tc.testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1             : Creating container for image: testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1
2024-01-22T20:26:34.275+01:00  INFO 11724 --- [my-service] [           main] o.t.utility.RegistryAuthLocator          : Credential helper/store (docker-credential-desktop) does not have credentials for https://index.docker.io/v1/
2024-01-22T20:26:34.339+01:00  INFO 11724 --- [my-service] [           main] tc.testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1             : Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 is starting: 3448a4e2e3e2889511d5acefe55cc5c9445c0f0510a4a1c33b3a1a156998e329
2024-01-22T20:26:34.493+01:00  INFO 11724 --- [my-service] [           main] tc.testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1             : Container testcontainers/ryuk:0.5.1 started in PT0.344189S
2024-01-22T20:26:34.494+01:00  WARN 11724 --- [my-service] [containers-ryuk] o.t.utility.RyukResourceReaper           : Can not connect to Ryuk at 127.0.0.1:32768

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:549) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:592) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751) ~[na:na]
    at org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper.lambda$null$1(RyukResourceReaper.java:105) ~[testcontainers-1.19.3.jar:1.19.3]
    at org.rnorth.ducttape.ratelimits.RateLimiter.doWhenReady(RateLimiter.java:27) ~[duct-tape-1.0.8.jar:na]
    at org.testcontainers.utility.RyukResourceReaper.lambda$maybeStart$2(RyukResourceReaper.java:101) ~[testcontainers-1.19.3.jar:1.19.3]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
```

I am using Docker Desktop for Mac v4.26.1, Spring boot 3, Java 17, testcontainers for postgresql v1.19.3, Tilt v0.33.10, Minikube v1.32.0.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the connection refused error, The first thing you need to check would be the network connection between the docker desktop and the tilt configuration. Make sure no network discrepancies that can hinder the connection between containers. Firewalls are normally the culprit so don’t forget to double check. Reboot your Docker Desktop if possible then check the daemon is working as expected. This documentation may come in handy as it is related to your issue.[1]

[1] https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/3422